# Связь many-to-many SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: sql-server, olap, ssas

Как организовать связь `Many-to-Many` в табулярной модели `SSAS 2016`. При графическом перетаскивании возникает ошибка повторяющихся строк в таблицах, составные ключи здесь не работают. Знаю что можно на `DAX` эту связь реализовать. Был ли у кого-нибудь опыт?

Comment: Вопрос еще актуален? Прошу привести схему данных витрины, тогда будет проще что-то советовать.

Comment: @SergeNazarenko, в общем я решил задачу по другому, я создал справочники, в которых удалил дубликаты номенклатур, но сохранил номера спецификаций. Связь организовал но номенклатуре многие - к - одному, если вы понимаете о чем я. А так задача была соединить таблицу фактов с измерениями, в обоих были дубликаты номенклатур.